# insert records in sql from local server to linked server that does not exist in linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * from TABLE_attendance
WHERE date NOT IN
  (SELECT * from [LINKED SERVER].DATABASENAME.dbo.TABLE_attendance where date = '06-09-15')
```

When I executed this query I got this error message:

> Msg 116, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 3 Only one expression can be specified in the select
>   list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I just wanted to check a records in linked server if the records are all existing from local server , if the linked server has no record on an specific date, then the local server will transfer data into linked server.

Please help me to solve this problem, Thank you :-)

Comment: Title, text, and query are not consistent.  You want to transfer ALL records if there is no data on a certain date.   Answer is no better than the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return more than one column in your subquery. Your query should be something like this

```
SELECT * from TABLE_attendance
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id
                 from [LINKED SERVER].DATABASENAME.dbo.TABLE_attendance
                 where date = '06-09-15')
```